# Issue with font number size when using A list aparts guide to avoide Faux bold

Tags: css, font-family, superscript

I'm using A list aparts guide to avoid Faux bolding of a font
http://alistapart.com/article/say-no-to-faux-bold

It's working perfectly in that all font's with style

```
font-weight: 600;
```

..are now using the bold font.

I have setup my font face as recommended in the article. So I'm using the same font family name and just changing the weight.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "freight-sans-pro";
  src: url("https://s3.amazonaws.com/visible-static/fonts/FreightSansProBook-Regular.eot") format("eot"),
       url("https://s3.amazonaws.com/visible-static/fonts/FreightSansProBook-Regular.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
       url("https://s3.amazonaws.com/visible-static/fonts/FreightSansProBook-Regular.otf")  format("opentype"),
       url("https://s3.amazonaws.com/visible-static/fonts/FreightSansProBook-Regular.woff") format("woff"),
       url("https://s3.amazonaws.com/visible-static/fonts/FreightSansProBook-Regular.ttf")  format("truetype"),
       url("https://s3.amazonaws.com/visible-static/fonts/FreightSansProBook-Regular.svg#freight-sans-pro") format("svg");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family:"freight-sans-pro";
  src: url("https://s3.amazonaws.com/visible-static/fonts/FreightSansProBook-Regular.eot"),
       url("https://s3.amazonaws.com/visible-static/fonts/FreightSansProBook-Regular.eot?iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
       url("https://s3.amazonaws.com/visible-static/fonts/FreightSansProBook-Regular.woff") format("woff"),
       url("https://s3.amazonaws.com/visible-static/fonts/FreightSansProBook-Regular.ttf") format("truetype"),
       url("https://s3.amazonaws.com/visible-static/fonts/FreightSansProBook-Regular.svg#din-condensed-web") format("svg");
  font-weight: 600;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

It's causing a strange issue with numbers in the font though. They are appearing smaller and with higher line height.

In this gif below, the top line has the number smaller as it's weight 600 and on the line below with the normal weight the number is not superscripted.

I can't recreate this in a fiddle though I've tried:
https://jsfiddle.net/snbo2dap/

...does anyone know what to look for or what I have done wrong to set this up?

[image: have to login to see issue so providing this]

Comment: gif is not enough. you need to create some demo or fiddle.

Comment: @locateganesh I can't recreate this unfortunately despite my efforts.
https://jsfiddle.net/snbo2dap/ so I've asked what would people look for as I can't see anything that is causing it.